# Flutter URL to create and open a new google drive folder

Tags: google-chrome, url, flutter, google-drive-api, flutter-dependencies

I'm wondering is there a URL I can run that will create a new Google Drive folder and then open it in the Google Drive app (on phone or tablet).

I know you can create the folder via the google drive API, but not open the Google Drive app it seems.
I'm looking for something like the Google Maps URL where you specify e.g. destination coordinates in the URL and it opens with the route to those coordinates.

Many thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that creating a folder that way is not possible. You can however, do it through the API. The flow would be as follows:

1. Your application requests the user's authorization.
2. The user logs in to his Google account and accepts.
3. Your application creates a folder in his Google Drive instance.
4. Your application retrieves the link of the newly created folder.
5. Your application opens the URL. In case the user has the "Google Drive" application, and he has not set Google Drive links to open with another app by default, it will be open with the app.

You can read more about how to create a Drive Folder using the Google Drive API for Dart here:

- [Dart GoogleAPIs Package](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis): Library to use several Google APIs.
- [Files create endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22mimeType%22%3A%22application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%22%7D%7D): Endpoint to call to create a folder. To create it, you will have to set the "mimeType" in the request body to: `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've been trying it, but am stuck on point 3, I can't find any documentation which shows me how to create a google drive folder from my flutter code I guess using the auth header or some other information from the Google sign in I made.

Comment: Hey @Kitcc, creating a folder using the Drive API is not trivial indeed. Sorry for not detailing that. To create a folder, you have to call the [Drive.Files.insert endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert) setting the `mimeType` property to the following: `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`. Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: Hey @Kitcc I suggest you visit [this link](https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_examples/blob/master/drive_upload_download_console/bin/main.dart). It's an example using dart to insert and download files in Google Drive. To create a folder, upon calling the function `api.files.insert`, you will have to provide a contentType parameter as follows: `api.files.insert(driveFile, contentType: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")`. Cheers

Comment: Hey @carlesgg97 thanks so much for all the help. I've actually got no 3. working!

Comment: A question regarding number 4 above.  From the response I get when the folder is created is it possible to get or derive the url share link to the folder, then I can just open it from my Flutter project.

Comment: @Kitcc Yes, you can get the link to it. To do this, obtain the "alternateLink" attribute from the response. You can see how the insert API call works and test it with [this link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert).

Comment: Hi @carlesgg97 thanks again. However I don't get a "alternateLink" attribute in the response.

Comment: @Kitcc how are you dealing with the response? Bear in mind the insert function returns a promise, so your code should look somewhat like: `api.files.insert(driveFile, contentType: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder").then((insertedFile) { var linkToFile = insertedFile.alternateLink })`

Comment: Hi again, @carlesgg97 one hopefully last question, I am getting very confused, actually am new to using the google api and also quite new to using Drive in this way so maybe there's something obvious that iam missing. I can't see any difference between the following two https requests:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1D3Nbu5oe_KllDMNDEAD--8VQuX9pPPEt

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1D3Nbu5oe_KIIDMNDEAD--8VQuX9pPPEt

Comment: However simply put the first works as expected and the other always shows a 404 error. Would you have any idea why this? The first is taken from the google drive application when i manually request a link to share, the second is from my GoogleApi response alternateLink.

Comment: @Kitcc Did you copy that ID manually? There are two characters (right after `1D3Nbu5oe_K`) that are different: in the first URL it's "l" (underscore L), in the second one, the one that causes the error, it's "I" twice (uppercase i). You may see it more clearly here: 1st link ID `1D3Nbu5oe_KllDMNDEAD--8VQuX9pPPEt`, 2nd link ID `1D3Nbu5oe_KIIDMNDEAD--8VQuX9pPPEt`

Comment: Ok I think I need a little break and a cup of tea! Yes that's exactly it, so all good. Many thanks for your help with this, it's been a voyage of discovery.

Comment: @Kitcc haha, no worries. Kindly consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if it was useful to you. And please, don't hesitate to post another question should you have any other doubt related to G Suite APIs. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, hope that it's ok if I reach out one more time on this topic. My final question is that, this is working great now creates and opens the google drive folder as expected on the web. However on my phone I also have the google drive application. Is it possible to tell it to open the google drive application if it is installed, instead of always opening google drive with the web version?